# Multiple Category Filter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm trying to build a filter function for my product list. If one or more attributes is selected it should fadeOut the not matching elements. Later it should also fade in again, if one filter is removed. I think my problem is, if the array doesn't match 100%, I don't get a true statement.

Hopefully you understand my problem and help me :-). Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.product-filter ul > li').click(function() {
        
        $(this).find('.level2').slideToggle();
    });
    
    $('.product-list-teaser').each(function() {
        var data = $(this).attr('data-filter'),
            data = data.split(' '),
            data = data.filter(Boolean),
            data = data.sort();
    
    
        $(this).attr('data-filter', data);
        
    
    })
    
    $('.product-filter .level2 li').click(function() {
        var content = $(this).text();
    
        $('.filter').append('<li>' + content + ' <span class="delete"></span></li>');
    
        var contentList = $('.filter li').text(),
            contentList = contentList.split(' '),
            contentList = contentList.filter(Boolean),
            contentList = contentList.sort();

    
        $('.product-list-teaser').each(function() {
    
            if($(this).attr('data-filter') == contentList) {
            
            $(this).fadeIn();;
        }
        else {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        }
    
        })
    
        
    
    });
    
    
    
    $('.filter').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    })

});
```

```css
.product-filter { position: relative; z-index: 20; }
.product-filter ul.categories { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.product-filter ul.categories li { list-style: none; float: left; width: calc(((100% - 220px) / 12) * 4 + (3 * 20px) - 10px); border: solid 5px #e2000a; margin: 0 20px 20px 0; text-align: center; color: #e2000a; font-weight: 700; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer; padding: 17px 0; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; position: relative;}
.product-filter ul.categories li:after { display: inline-block; width: 13px; height: 12px; background: url('../img/sub-toggle.png') no-repeat 0 0; background-size: 30px; margin-top: 7px; content: ""; margin-left: 10px; background-position: 0 -16px;}
.product-filter ul.categories li:hover { background: #e2000a; color: #fff;}
.product-filter ul.categories li:nth-child(3n+3) { margin-right: 0; }
.product-filter .categories .level2 { display: none; position: absolute; left: -5px; top: 64px; background: #fff; border: solid 5px #e2000a; z-index: 20; border-top: none; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.product-filter .categories .level2 li { border: none; padding: 10px 0; color: #000; font-size: 18px; line-height: 25px; float: none; margin: 0; font-weight: 300; width: 100%}
.product-filter .categories .level2 li:after { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-wrap">
    <div class="product-filter">
        <ul class="categories">
            <li>Category1
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li>aerob</li>
                    <li>anaerob</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Category2
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li>industry</li>
                    <li>electronic</li>
                    <li>mechanic</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Category3
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li>white</li>
                    <li>blue</li>
                    <li>black</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="filter">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product-inner-wrap">
        <div class="product-list-teaser" data-filter="aerob industry blue">
            <p>Product aerob industry blue</p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-list-teaser" data-filter="aerob industry white">
            <p>Product aerob industry white</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need the elements that have been selected to disappear from the dropdown menus?

Comment: No, the dropdown menu is my filter. If you chose one filter category it will be added between the dropdown and my product list as a filter list. So you can see which filter is active at the moment. If you click on an element in the filter list of active filter, this filter should be removed. The product-list-teaser elements should be filtered with all active filter.

Comment: That functionality seems to be working to me. I can add one or multiple filters from the dropdown lists and when I click on a list element below it's been removed. I don't see where the problem is. Do you mind sharing some more info or an example that could help us understand your issue?

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm not good in explaining :D. It's easier if you open the fiddle. If you open it, you can see my dropdown filter and my product examples „Product aerob industry blue” and „Product aerob industry white”. If you choose now from the dropdown category1 > aerob both products disappear, but they shouldn't because they got the data-filter „aerob”. Imagine it like a shop filter. If you choose blue, you would like to see all products with the tag „blue”, doesn't matter if shoes or shirts. Products without should fade out. If you add the tag „shoes”, only blue shoes should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do this as quickly as I could but it came out a bit messy. There are much more elegant ways to achieve this. I did some modifications to your JS code but it doesn't handle the case where all the filters are removed, you will need to reset the product list.

Edit: The function `includes` that searches inside an array to find if the given element exists is not supported by all browsers as it came with the ES7 specification. You can check [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) for the compatibility

I hope this works for you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.product-filter ul > li').click(function() {
        
        $(this).find('.level2').slideToggle();
    });
    
    
    $('.product-filter .level2 li').click(function() {
        var content = $(this).text();
    
        $('.filter').append('<li>' + content + ' <span class="delete"></span></li>');
    
        var contentList = $('.filter li').text(),
            contentList = contentList.split(' '),
            contentList = contentList.filter(Boolean),
            contentList = contentList.sort();

        $('.product-list-teaser').each(function() {
            var thisProduct = $(this);
            
            var productData = $(this).attr('data-filter'),
            productData = productData.split(' ');
            
            contentList.forEach( function(el) {
              if(productData.includes(el)) {
                  thisProduct.fadeIn();
              }
              else {
                  thisProduct.fadeOut();
              }
            } )
            
         })
    
        
    
    });
    
    
    
    $('.filter').on('click', 'li', function() {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    })

});
```

```css
.product-filter { position: relative; z-index: 20; }
.product-filter ul.categories { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.product-filter ul.categories li { list-style: none; float: left; width: calc(((100% - 220px) / 12) * 4 + (3 * 20px) - 10px); border: solid 5px #e2000a; margin: 0 20px 20px 0; text-align: center; color: #e2000a; font-weight: 700; font-size: 25px; line-height: 30px; cursor: pointer; padding: 17px 0; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; position: relative;}
.product-filter ul.categories li:after { display: inline-block; width: 13px; height: 12px; background: url('../img/sub-toggle.png') no-repeat 0 0; background-size: 30px; margin-top: 7px; content: ""; margin-left: 10px; background-position: 0 -16px;}
.product-filter ul.categories li:hover { background: #e2000a; color: #fff;}
.product-filter ul.categories li:nth-child(3n+3) { margin-right: 0; }
.product-filter .categories .level2 { display: none; position: absolute; left: -5px; top: 64px; background: #fff; border: solid 5px #e2000a; z-index: 20; border-top: none; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.product-filter .categories .level2 li { border: none; padding: 10px 0; color: #000; font-size: 18px; line-height: 25px; float: none; margin: 0; font-weight: 300; width: 100%}
.product-filter .categories .level2 li:after { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-wrap">
    <div class="product-filter">
        <ul class="categories">
            <li>Category1
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li>aerob</li>
                    <li>anaerob</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Category2
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li>industry</li>
                    <li>electronic</li>
                    <li>mechanic</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Category3
                <ul class="level2">
                    <li>white</li>
                    <li>blue</li>
                    <li>black</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="filter">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="product-inner-wrap">
        <div class="product-list-teaser" data-filter="aerob industry blue">
            <p>Product aerob industry blue</p>
        </div>
        <div class="product-list-teaser" data-filter="aerob industry white">
            <p>Product aerob industry white</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```